# Obter latitude e longitude

Tags: ios, objective-c

Eu gostaria de saber como obter a latitude e longitude em iOS usando **Objective-C**. Alguém poderia me ajudar? Já segui vários exemplos mas nenhum exibe as informações corretas.

Answer (score 1):

A partir do **iOS 8** você precisa de alguns passos além do que estávamos acostumados antes da atualização do sistema, talvez isto que faltou nos tutoriais que você encontrou pela web pois me deparei com esta mesma situação.

No seu arquivo `Info.plist`, existem duas propriedades que você pode adicionar (utilize o modo texto):

Para obter localização enquanto o aplicativo estiver rodando (mesmo em *background*):

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Mensagem para o usuário</string>
```

Para obter localização enquanto o aplicativo estiver em primeiro plano apenas:

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Mensagem para o usuário</string>
```

Depois de importar o *framework* **CoreLocation** ao seu projeto, adicione o seguinte *delegate* no seu arquivo **.h**:

```
@interface LocalizacaoViewController: UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
```

E então inicie a busca no seu arquivo de implementação:

```
if (self.locManager == nil) {
    self.locManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    [self.locManager setDelegate:self];
    [self.locManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation];
}

// Verificação de recurso apenas para iOS 8
if ([self.locManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
    [self.locManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]; // Ou requestAlwaysAuthorization
}

[self.locManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

E por fim, a implementação dos métodos de *delegate*:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // Erro
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    CLLocation *lastLocation = [locations lastObject];

    // Latitude: lastLocation.coordinate.latitude
    // Longitude: lastLocation.coordinate.longitude
}
```

Nestes métodos, a menos que você diga para encerrar a atualização da localização com `[self.locManager stopUpdatingLocation]`, eles serão executados toda vez que houver mudança.

Veja se consegue sucesso com a implementação desta maneira.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas realizei o procedimento e continua não exibindo.

Comment: Bruno, você está testando no aparelho ou no simulador? Algo no log? Experimentou colocar breakpoints para ver até onde está chegando?

Comment: @BrunoRichart se conseguiu resolver com essa resposta, considere marcar esta como correta para que sirva de referências para outros com a mesma dúvida.